# how to fix Deprecated: curl_setopt() in tmhOAuth.php (twitter)

Tags: php, curl, twitter, deprecated

i use PHP Version 5.5.9

try to post image to twitter, but i have this warning :

```
Deprecated: curl_setopt(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_folder\libs\tmhOAuth\tmhOAuth.php on line 771
```

when i check the script on the file tmhOAuth.php is like this :

```
758    $c = curl_init();
759    switch ($this->request_settings['method']) {
760      case 'GET':
761        if (isset($this->request_settings['querystring']))
762          $this->request_settings['url'] = $this->request_settings['url'] . '?' . $this->request_settings['querystring'];
763        break;
764      case 'POST':
765        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
766        if (isset($this->request_settings['postfields']))
767          $postfields = $this->request_settings['postfields'];
768        else
769          $postfields = array();
770
771        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
772        break;
773      default:
774        if (isset($this->request_settings['postfields']))
775          curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $this->request_settings['postfields']);
776    }
```

how do I fix this..?

Answer (score 1):

You need to process all your files with function `curl_file_create();`, 
f.e.

```
<?php
    $path = '/path/to/file';
    $file = curl_file_create($path);
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => $file));
```

[link to man [curl_file_create]](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-file-create.php)

Comment: when i use curl_file_create i have this warning "Catchable fatal error: Object of class CURLFile could not be converted to string .."

Comment: $image = "C:/xampp/htdocs/project_folder/photos/small_1412933689.jpg";  
$img   = curl_file_create($image);
$code = $tmhOAuth->user_request(array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'url'  => "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json",
              'params' => array(
                                'media[]'   => "@".$img.";type=image/jpeg;filename={$imagename}",
                                'status'    => $_SESSION['content_text']),
              'multipart' => true
));

Comment: @a.fauzi remove all text in 'media[]' => .. it needs to be only $img, like this `...'media[]' => $img, 'status' =>...`